# How to find inverse Laplace transform of the following function?

Tags: laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

$ X(s) = \frac{s}{s^4+1} $

I tried to use the definition:
$ f(t) = \mathcal{L}^{-1} \{F(s)\} = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \lim_{T\to\infty}\int_{ \gamma - i T}^{ \gamma + i T} e^{st} F(s)\,ds $

or the partial fraction expansion but I have not achieved results.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** With
$$s^4+1=s^4+1+2s^2-2s^2=(s^2+1-\sqrt{2}s)(s^2+1+\sqrt{2}s)$$
then
$$\dfrac{s}{s^4+1}=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\dfrac{1}{s^2+1-\sqrt{2}s}-\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\dfrac{1}{s^2+1-\sqrt{2}s}$$
then complete the squares in denominators!

Comment: Youre welcome!.

Comment: I still have another question for you. When asked to anti-transform into $ Res(s) > \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} $  does not change anything for calculation?

Comment: calculations are the same!

Comment: Thanks again! :)

Comment: Happy new year :)

Comment: Happy New Year to you too! Can you help me with another questions?https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2588813/how-to-find-fourier-serie-and-transform