# How to find Fourier serie and transform?

Tags: fourier-series, fourier-transform

I have to calculate Fourier serie and Fourier transform of periodic extension, of period $T=2$ of the following function:

$ x_0(t) = e^{−2|t−1|}(u(t) − u(t − 2))$

I derived two times and then transformed. The result is the following:

$X_0(\omega)=\frac{\frac{2}{e^2}+\frac{2}{e^2}e^{-2j\omega}-\frac{1}{e^2}j{\omega}e^{-2j\omega}+\frac{1}{e^2}j\omega-4e^{-j\omega}}{-4-\omega^2}$

Now I know that I have to sample in $(\omega_ok)$ with $\omega_0=\pi$

$X_0(k\pi)=\frac{\frac{2}{e^2}+\frac{2}{e^2}e^{-2jk\pi}-\frac{1}{e^2}j{k\pi}e^{-2jk\pi}+\frac{1}{e^2}jk\pi-4e^{-jk\pi}}{-4-(k\pi)^2}=\frac{4(-1)^k-\frac{4}{e^2}}{4+(k\pi)^2}$

discontinuity in $\pm(\frac{2j}{\pi})$

I would like to know how to proceed to find coefficients, Fourier serie and Fourier transform with these complex discontinuities

Comment: You can easily write
$$
x_0(t)=
\begin{cases}
0&t\leq0,\\
e^{2(t-1)}&0<t\leq1,\\
e^{-2(t-1)}&1<t\leq2,\\
0&t\geq2.
\end{cases}
$$
and find it's Fourier series.

Comment: thank you very much for the suggestion!